# KVM Switch for keyboard and mouse only

Tags: keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

How are you using just a KVM switch for just the keyboard and mouse? I have 2 monitors each connected to each tower. Now, I am unsure of how to get the mouse and keyboard situated. I have an old TRENDnet TK-207 switch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TRENDnet TK-207 switch usage infographics [image: .]
[source](https://www.trendnet.com/products/KVM-2-Port-switch/TK-207K)

Just connect your hardware as shown on picture. In order to use two monitors, you need a VGA splitter inserted between KVM and monitors.

Comment: @Ashley Tell us if it works by accepting and voting for an answer.